# Going out of loop Perl

Tags: perl, loops

I have two arrays, I am evaluating the values of one array with other. What i have done is

```
@array_x= qw(1 5 3 4 6);
@array_y= qw(-3 4 2 1 3);

foreach $x (@array_x){
    foreach $y (@array_y){
        if ($x-$y > 0){
            next;
        }
        print "$x\n";
    }
}
```

Here, problem is , in array_x, its first index i.e 1-(-3)=4, it satisfies, but next 1-4=-3 is not satisfying the condition, hence it should break the loop and go for next element of array_x. Here only 5 and 6 satisfies the condition with all elements of array_y, so i should get only 5,6 in the output.

Answer (score 4):

Here is your loops with labels so you can break to the outer level:

```
XVALUE:
foreach $x (@array_x){
    YVALUE:
    foreach $y (@array_y){
        if ($x-$y > 0){
            next XVALUE;
        }
        print "$x\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If the OP is more interested in breaking out of the outer loop than the test in question, then this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can label each loop and exit the one you want. See [perldoc last](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html)

E.g.:

```
LINE: while (<STDIN>) {
    last LINE if /^$/; # exit when done with header
    #...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the intention is to just find the elements which are greater than the element in the subsequent list, the following would find it in 1 iteration of each array.

```
use strict;

my @array_x= qw(1 5 3 4 6);    
my @array_y= qw(-3 4 2 1 3);    
my $max_y = $array_y[0];

foreach my $y (@array_y) {    
   $max_y = $y if $y > $max_y;    
}

foreach my $x (@array_x) {    
   print "\nX=$x" if $x > $max_y;
}
```

Output:

```
X=5 
X=6
```

Comment: `use List::Util 'max';` `my $max_y = max @array_y;`

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what is your need, but is this what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my @array_x= qw(1 5 3 4 6);
my @array_y= qw(-3 4 2 1 3);
foreach my $x(@array_x){
    my $OK=1;
    foreach my $y(@array_y){
        next if $x > $y;
        $OK=0;
        last;
    }
    say "x=$x" if $OK;
}
```

**output:**

```
x=5
x=6
```

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array_x= qw(1 5 3 4 6);
my @array_y= qw(-3 4 2 1 3);
LABEL: for my $x (@array_x) {
    for my $y (@array_y) {
        next LABEL unless $x > $y;
    }
    print "$x\n";
 }
```

Comment: No, i dont need larger values, my prob is to skip checking other if it is not satisfied in first step itself and go to next element.

Comment: @gthm: That's what you'll end up with though. I changed my answer to implement the algorithm you seem to be describing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to rethink your method. You want to find all values in `@x` which are greater than all in `@y`. You shouldn't loop over all `@y` each time, you should find the max of it, then filter on the max.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'max';

my @x= qw(1 5 3 4 6);
my @y= qw(-3 4 2 1 3);

my $ymax = max @y;

my @x_result = grep { $_ > $ymax } @x;
```

Or since I am crazy about the new `state` keyword:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.10.0;

use List::Util 'max';

my @x= qw(1 5 3 4 6);
my @y= qw(-3 4 2 1 3);

my @x_result = grep { state $ymax = max @y; $_ > $ymax } @x;
```

Edit: on re-reading previous answers, this is the same concept as angel_007, though I think this implementation is more self-documenting/readable.

Comment: Thank you, but my aim is to learn about skipping out of loops, not to find maximum numbers.